# Insert Google Earth placeholder into a KML file

Tags: qgis, polygon, kml

I've loaded a KML file of polygons into Google Maps, created using QGIS but the name of each polygon/area isn't showing in Google Maps - shown as 'untitled'. I gather you may have to enter the name of the polygon into the KML file. Is there any way of adding the name of each polygon in the Google Maps placeholder using QGIS or other tools such as notepad/text editor?

Answer (score 1):

If you open your KML file in a text editor, you will find a line like that for each of your polygons:

```
<name>Feature_Name</name>
```

Here, you can enter the names for each polygon seperately (replace *Feature_Name* or whatever is shown there for your file).
Alternatively, you can add a column "name" to your file in QGIS where you insert the name to be displayed, and the KML file should recognize it automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this, your reply prompted to have a look at the export file/save as tab in QGIS, there is an option when saving to kml to specify the name field in qgis which will be inserted into the kml file